# How can I enable 64-bit Android libraries, in react native version <59

Tags: android, react-native

our current application is on react-native version 0.58.0 as per the new updates in play store, apk should have 64-bit libraries.
React native official documentation asks to update to 0.59.0 version. 0.59 version brings some breaking changes to the legacy application. 
If we only upgrade the build.gradle file to have as suggested [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/compare/version/0.58.0...version/0.59.1#diff-ff98181a06bca8786b0ee4fc019f0335) will have any side effect in the production build?

After this build.gradle change we don't see any error while uploading the application to play store.

Is it mandate to upgrade to 0.59.0 RN version for 64-bit Android version?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have a choice.  RN runs on a javascript interpreter written in C and bundled with RN.  THat didn't have 64 bit binaries until 59.  Unless you want to redo most of the work they did in upgrading yourself, you're going to have to upgrade RN.

Comment: is there any way to check what is the version of binaries packaged inside the apk for  the RN javascript interpreter?